# Efficiency when fetching data from core data and multithreading

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, thread-safety

I've been having trouble with Core Data and multithreading for a while, and I have to say it's driving me crazy. After reading some blogs and the Apple Docs I have seen that the recommended way is creating a `NSManagedObjectContext` (moc) for each thread, and a shared `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  But as I'm using NSOperations, and they aren't attached to a specific thread, I have to create a new moc for each operation.

So each time I create a moc, I set the store coordinator to the mock and I fetch some data with it. Then, if I need to use the objects I've fetched in another thread, let's say in foreground for example, I should obtain them again, creating a new moc, and using `existingObjectWithID:error:`.

But, as far as I know, there is no method receiving an array of object ids, so I have to use that call (`existingObjectWithID:error:`) for each object, which means it might be looping for a while, let's say 100 times for example.

**My question is:** is this the right way? Am I missing something? Is it faster than directly retrieving data from the main thread?

The most information I found was about modifying data in different threads, but I've found almost nothing about fetching.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which version of iOS are you targeting?

Comment: Both iOS 4 and iOS 5 (different projects)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSManagedObjectContext objects are not thread-safe. This means that if you wish to access Core Data from multiple threads, you will need one for each thread (and created on the thread too). Each of these can use the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, which will serialise access to the persistent store.